# Changing a web app's homescreen icon

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts, home-screen, bookmarks, app-icons

I use Chrome's 'Add to homescreen' feature to add web app shortcuts to my homescreen. As a user, how do I change a shortcut's homescreen icon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any launcher (eg. [Nova Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher&hl=en)).

- When you add the shortcut to the home screen, press and hold on the
  shortcut icon, tap `Edit`.
- After this, it will open a dialog box to edit the caption along with the icon. Tap on the icon and select the required one from your phone.